# how to modify slimbox to close by clicking on expanded image

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2, slimbox

I am using Slimbox 1.71 for MooTools 1.2 ( [Demo](http://www.digitalia.be/demo/slimbox/) )
I would like to close the expanded Image if I click on the expanded image itself.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying the core script is bad practice (say you update the script - you'll lose your changes). It's actually better to add a code snippet after the library is loaded, and operational:

```
document.id('lbImage').addEvent('click', function(){
    document.id('lbCloseLink').fireEvent('click');
});
```

Comment: yeah, this is what happens when you write code that does not extend well. it's not a class, it has no events, makes it very hard to work with it. if it had been a class with onOpen / onClose events, all you would have had to do was pass on `onOpen: function() { this.something.addEvent("click", this.close.bind(this)) }` and be done with it... should really look at using something more recent.

Answer (score 0):

**Find:**

```
id:"lbCenter"
```

**Replace:**

```
id:"lbCenter", events: {click: close}
```